# Has the Google Analytics script block changed?

Tags: google-analytics

I've been given some code to put into a couple of sites, as below (tracking id amended)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-99999999-99']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

But I've just created a new GA account, and the script GA states to add is below: (again tracking id amended)

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-99999999-99', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Has this "standard" code changed recently or is there another reason for the difference? I'm trying to pre-empt a "why isn't this the code we sent you?" question if I use the code GA has asked me to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two versions of Google Analytics.

> Classic analytics which uses ga.js  your first snippet.

and

> Universal analytics which uses analytics.js your second snippet.

If you have an older Google Analytics account you may be using the old snippet.  All new sites are created using Universal analytics and should use the new snippet.

Technically speaking even old sits should start using the new snippet but the old snippet will still work for them.   I don't think that new sites can use the old snippet tbh there would really be no point in doing so because so many features are not supported in it.

So who ever sent you that snippet is behind times and didn't realize that there is a new version of Google Analytics.

Comment: Terrific. Thanks DalmTo. Just what I was after.

Comment: now email who ever sent you that snippet and look all smart telling them they should be aware of the new version of google analytics and its features.  :)

Comment: You should be using Universal Snippet. Classic still works but it's old now and expected to be deprecated at some point in the future. Plus some Google Analytics features are only supported with Universal Analytics which at this point is 100% stable.